# How can I deploy a Go app along with MediaWiki using Apache?

Tags: apache, go, mediawiki

Let's say I have the following simple Go web app:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I have a website which is hosted by my university (`www.univ.edu/me`) and currently I have a wiki setup under `www.univ.edu/me/wiki` and it works fine. My question is how I can deploy the above Go app there so it can be accessed through  `www.univ.edu/me/mygoapp`?

I have found some solutions but they all appear to require root privileges. In my case, I don't have root access and I'm not able to modify the configuration of server, which most likely is Apache.

**Update:** Thanks for your replies. It appears that in my case, the Apache server is on a separate machine than the one which physically hosts my website files. The machine/IP that has the Apache, refuses ssh connections so there's no direct way to check the server's configuration.

Comment: Is Go even installed?

Comment: Yes, it is installed in my home folder.

Comment: do you have access to fcgi? is so, you can write your go server to that spec with http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/ and deploy it as a binary. I've done this in the past with bluehost.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Apaches `mod_proxy`. It offers proxying another HTTP Server when certain virtual directories are requested:

```
<Location /goapp/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
```

You may need to do additional changes to your Apache config to make sure the request gets passed through properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have write access to the `.htaccess` file in your MediaWiki installation you may be able to add:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

This is dependant on the global Apache configuration, as [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) is often disabled or restricted on premises like Universities, but it's worth a try.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse for more details.